Speed up kafka on a single machine
I am trying to speed up my kafka pipeline without using multiple machines. I tried various numbers of partitions but max out at around 1.5M events/sec input speed and 2.7M events/sec output speed. How can I speed up my pipeline further?
I already achieve a CPU utilization of 100% on all cores. Does this mean I am at the limit? This would be disappointing because my throughput is only ~30MB/sec and I can achieve higher throughput by packing more data into each event.
Here is my setup:
docker-compose.yml:
services:
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.7.1
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      # KRaft settings
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka:9093
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
      # Listeners
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
      # Clustering
      - KAFKA_CFG_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR=1

run_experiment.sh:
#!/bin/bash

##############
# PARAMETERS #
##############

TOTAL=10000000
NUM_PARTITIONS=${1:-1}
PRODUCE_PER_PARTITION=$((TOTAL / NUM_PARTITIONS))
CONSUME_PER_PARTITION=$(echo "0.9 * $PRODUCE_PER_PARTITION / 1" | bc)  # consume slightly less messages to account for imbalanced partitions

###########
# PREPARE #
###########

docker compose down

echo "Start and wait for kafka..."
docker compose up -d
sleep 15

echo "Prepare topic..."
docker compose exec kafka kafka-topics.sh --create --topic testTopic --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --partitions $NUM_PARTITIONS --replication-factor 1

##########
# HELPER #
##########

profile() {
  if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: time_wrapper number command"
    return 1
  fi

  local number=$1
  shift
  local command=("$@")

  local start_time=$(date +%s.%N)
  "${command[@]}"
  local end_time=$(date +%s.%N)

  local duration=$(echo "$end_time - $start_time" | bc)
  local result=$(echo "scale=0; $number / $duration / 1000" | bc)

  echo "Throughput: ${result}K events/sec, total duration $duration seconds"
}

###########
# PRODUCE #
###########

echo "Produce data ($NUM_PARTITIONS partitions, $PRODUCE_PER_PARTITION messages each)..."
profile $((NUM_PARTITIONS*PRODUCE_PER_PARTITION)) docker compose exec kafka bash -c """
for ((i = 0; i < $NUM_PARTITIONS; i++)); do
    seq 1 $PRODUCE_PER_PARTITION | \
    sed 's/.*/message &/' | \
    kafka-console-producer.sh \
        --topic testTopic \
        --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 \
        >/dev/null & \
done
wait
"""

###########
# CONSUME #
###########

echo "Consume data ($NUM_PARTITIONS partitions, $CONSUME_PER_PARTITION messages each)..."
profile $((NUM_PARTITIONS*CONSUME_PER_PARTITION)) docker compose exec kafka bash -c """
for ((i = 0; i < $NUM_PARTITIONS; i++)); do
    kafka-console-consumer.sh \
        --topic testTopic \
        --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 \
        --from-beginning \
        --max-messages $CONSUME_PER_PARTITION \
        --partition \$i >/dev/null & \
done
wait
"""

Output:
$ ./run_experiment.sh 3

[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container minimal_slow_consume_example-kafka-1  Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.1s 
 ✔ Network minimal_slow_consume_example_default    Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.1s 
Start and wait for kafka...
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network minimal_slow_consume_example_default    Created                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 ✔ Container minimal_slow_consume_example-kafka-1  Started                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.2s 
Prepare topic...
Created topic testTopic.
Produce data (3 partitions, 3333333 messages each)...
Throughput: 1776K events/sec, total duration 5.630058763 seconds
Consume data (3 partitions, 2999999 messages each)...
Processed a total of 2999999 messages
Processed a total of 2999999 messages
Processed a total of 2999999 messages
Throughput: 2484K events/sec, total duration 3.621851388 seconds

$ ./run_experiment.sh 5

[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container minimal_slow_consume_example-kafka-1  Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.9s 
 ✔ Network minimal_slow_consume_example_default    Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.2s 
Start and wait for kafka...
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network minimal_slow_consume_example_default    Created                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 ✔ Container minimal_slow_consume_example-kafka-1  Started                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.3s 
Prepare topic...
Created topic testTopic.
Produce data (5 partitions, 2000000 messages each)...
Throughput: 1728K events/sec, total duration 5.784597305 seconds
Consume data (5 partitions, 1800000 messages each)...
Processed a total of 1800000 messages
Processed a total of 1800000 messages
Processed a total of 1800000 messages
Processed a total of 1800000 messages
Processed a total of 1800000 messages
Throughput: 2611K events/sec, total duration 3.445952731 seconds

